# SSRS Error: Could not load folder content. SQL Server 2016

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, reportbuilder3.0

I am experiencing something new on my side today. All my reports are not loading.

I get this error:

> Could not load folder contents: Something went wrong in Report builder. SSRS SQL Server 2016

I tried to restart SQL Server Reporting Services and tried to set it to delay start but I still get the same error.

[screen mock-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIo74.png)

Comment: Possible resolution... Found this on dba stackexchange... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214271/ssrs-report-error-could-not-load-folder-contents-something-went-wrong-please-t

Comment: Refer to my answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/322333/230585

Answer (score 1):

Is it still relevant? Try to add rights in two places:
1) settings --> security --> add user
2) go to root folder, there is "manage folder" button, go to security --> add user. 
That'll work